# Tracking image not shown in Gmail

Tags: php, gmail

I have a newsletter template to send to all my subscribers and I want to track the open rate and click rate. So, I attached a php file (with tracking code) using img tag. But, the image is not shown. I searched about it and I came to know about that reason. Gmail allows image only from trusted source. What should I do to track open and click rate? Is there any possibility to track it using google analytics? or any other ways are there? Actually, I will send the newsletter template using php code only not manually.

Comment: show your code.